# How can one make Apache mod_expire to cache data for less then 24 hours?

Tags: apache2

I know that the default mod_expire caching daytime for all anonymous users is 24 hours. How can one make Apache mod_expire to cache data for less then 24 hours?, say for 12 hours?

Should this pass?

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 12 hours"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 12 hours"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those should pass according to the official documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)

It can be set as per the following:

- years
- months
- weeks
- days
- hours
- minutes
- seconds